# When to use "justifications" (plural)?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

In my book, I came across the phrase **"some justification"**.

I googled for it, "**justification**" can be countable or uncountable, but I have never heard that people used "***justifications***".

When should we treat the word as a countable noun and use "***justifications***" (the plural form)?

I did some research [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/justification) but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: You can use the plural when you want an enumerated list "What justifications are there for having done this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *some* means

> [some](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/some)
>   1. being an undetermined or unspecified one

So there isn't an issue regarding plurality: *justification* can be singular.

You can use *justification* as a plural like you would with *good reason*.

Here is an example in the same sense as your example. *I don't know why there were budget cuts. There must be some good reason for the recent budget cuts* →

> 1. There must be some justification for the recent budget cuts.

There can also be multiple undetermined justifications. *I don't know why there were budget cuts. There must be some good reasons for the recent budget cuts* →

> 2. There must be some justifications for the recent budget cuts.

If there is just one justification for a particular action, then *justification* (singular) is correct.

> 3. We have just one justification for the recent budget cuts.

If there are more than one reasons for a particular action, then *justification**s*** (plural) is correct. For example, imagine that there are ten reasons for the budget cuts, but only three are presented: *here are some reasons for the recent budget cuts*→

> 4. Here are some justifications for the recent budget cuts.

Here's a headline I found online that uses *justifications*.

> [18 Solid Justifications for Cloud Computing -- and 10 Situations Where It Doesn't Work](http://www.forbes.com/sites/joemckendrick/2012/09/10/18-solid-justifications-for-cloud-computing-and-10-situations-where-it-doesnt-work/#3c5bb500dc63)